# visual studio 2015 ignores tsconfig.json

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am working on angular application on the visual studio and keep getting

Property '' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

even toggling strictPropertyInitialization properties off on the tsconfig.json

I am using typescript 2.7.2 currently. I am suspecting there is another tsconfig in the memory somehow or another directory?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for 2015, but the solution for 2017 worked for me:

Quoting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/javascript-in-vs-2017#override-defaults

> You can override the default configuration by adding a tsconfig.json file to your project root. A tsconfig.json has several different options that can manipulate your project context. A few of them are listed below, but for a full set of all options available, see the schema store.